# How to make a futuristic helmet visor/mask material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

How to make similar material to the mask from the picture (the red\orange thing)?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Don't make comment as an answer, If it helps you, you can accept my answer and/or upvote.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 5):

[image: final]

It's pretty simple. Basically it's just Principled BSDF.

[image: nodes]

Set:

- **Color** to #F7E4D3
- **Metallic** to 1
- **Roughness** to 0.4
- **Anisotropic** to 1
- **Anisotropic** **Rotation** - here is 0.2 but for another mesh it could be
  different value. Tweak it as needed.

Comment: Thank you! I can't try it right now, but i'll check this later!